# BaseAdapter with sections, listview - adding cursor list data

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new here and would be great if someone could help me with this small crisis I have been having. I have been following Jeff Sharkeys Separate List Adapter tutorial which can be found [here](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) and I got it all working appropriately to how he explains it.

My problem is I have a database, pre made one which has a table that I am trying to put the extracted data into a list view using Jeffs adapter. I need this data to be put in different sections according to the Category ID column.

The table I am currently extracting data from is the Food table, which has 6 columns, categoriID, menuID, Item, Description, price and a PK _id

My database works properly as in other activities I use a SimpleCursorAdapter to bind data to a list view. (from other tables)

I use the following method in the Database Helper class to retrieve the data I need

```
public List<FoodModel> getData(String catid, String menuid) {
            List<FoodModel> FoodListModel = new ArrayList<FoodModel>();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(FOOD_TABLE, new String [] {FOODITEM_COLUMN, FOODITEMDESCRIPTION_COLUMN,FOODPRICE_COLUMN}, "catid = ? AND menuid = ?",
      new String[] { catid, menuid},null, null, null, null);   

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        FoodModel FoodModel = new FoodModel();
            FoodModel.setItem(cursor.getString(0));
            FoodModel.setdescrription(cursor.getString(1));
            FoodModel.setprice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
            FoodListModel.add(FoodModel);} while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
return FoodListModel;
 }
```

the Food Model class is the standard get set class to store the cursors data.

This public method works accordingly as in my main activity (jeffs ListSample.java) I output to the log cat the required information using

```
   Log.d("Reading: ", "Testing Cursor");
            List<FoodModel> Data1 =  dba.getData("1", "1");
            for (FoodModel fd : Data1){
                String log = "Item: "+fd.getitem()+" ,Description: " + fd.getdescription() + " ,Price: " + fd.getprice(); 
                Log.d("Name: ", log);
```

This outputs a list of all the data I need to put into 1 section of the SeperateListAdapter but to the log cat

The 3 things i am trying to output to the list view are the Item, description and price.

My problem is How do I add this data to the list view under the correct section?

as oposed to manually inserting it as Jeff shows

```
   List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
                    security.add(createItem("Remember passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
                    security.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
                    security.add(createItem("Show security warnings", "Show warning if there is a problem with a site's security"));
```

I didn't want to start my first experience of using this site by pasting all my classes is as this is my first time using this website, my English is not the best and it took me a while to write this I hope it is acceptable as a question, I would be really great full if someone could kindly help me or point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**  Will gladly post the rest of my code just didnt whant to bombard everyone with loads of information